# h2 going right up to top of next div

Tags: html, css

I have a h2 tag, the a div with some boxes in and the same again. However the h2 has a border top and that border top is going all the way up to the top of the div before, even though it is outside that div.

I have made a jsfiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjYhg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood right, the problem is that upper div is floated to left. Solution is add `clear: both;` (or `clear: left;`) to `h2`.

```
h2 {
    font-family: BebasNeue;
    color: #777878;
    font-size: 50px;
    border-top: 3px dashed #777878;
    border-bottom: 3px dashed #777878;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add clear: both; to the H2 tag in your CSS.  That tells the H2s to bump down below whatever page element is above them.